# Why mixing water with ethanol produces heat energy?

Tags: water, alcohols, heat, solvents, hydrogen-bond

Sorry if I'm asking something stupid but I'm trying to understand where this energy gets from. As far as I could find, it is not a reaction as both chemicals left unchanged, so it might have something to do with hydrogen bonding but I can't connect these two facts together.

**UPD**: it is not homework question (I have a degree in a completely unrelated field) and I did try to find a reasonable explanation in search engines but with no luck. Atm my theory is that ethanol creates H-bonds with water and those bonds have less energy than the ones between H2O-H2O and the excess of the energy goes away as heat but I don't have anybody who could confirm or reject that. As for the forums - Stack Exchange branches to me is the most credible source so I went asking here first.

Comment: There is not much to connect. Some compounds like to stay together, some don't.

Comment: why minus? if you see how to improve the question - let me know, otherwise your downvote is kinda pointless ;)

Comment: I don't know why minus. Guess someone doesn't like something about your question. To me, it's OK. Here, have a plus.

Comment: @skwisgaar, don't be discouraged by minus or pluses. These upvotes or downvotes don't mean anything in real life (may be in the virtual world). It is a good question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it's a homework question discussed in the majority of introductory chemistry books, and yes, you are right, it's about H-bonding.

Comment: @andselisk my field is pretty far from chemistry so I'd really appreciate if you advice some book where this topic is discussed. For now all I could find is that H-bond is responsible for H2O higher melting/boiling point (compared to, e. g. H2S), so, I presume, it keeps molecules together and requires additional energy to break this bond. But I'm not sure how it is connected to mixing with ethanol - maybe it creates bonds with smaller energy or simply breaks some of existing ones in the water, can't find anything definitive

Comment: @skwisgaar Note that the liquid also decreases it's volume after mixing and cooling down. It provides a hint about better intermolecular bonding.